# how to update grid row silently in Kendo UI?

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

I am calling a Web API using AJAX to get the latest data for a selected record as below:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'Get',
    url: _apiPath + "DataEntry/" + e.model.id,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(e.model.fields, function (index, value) { 
            if (data[index] != null) {
                e.model.set(index, data[index]);                                                
            }
        });
    }});
}
```

Its getting the data correctly. But when updating the data into the model, its not working sometimes. Also it adds a red triangle to the corner of the cell. Is there a better way to do this? I already tried datasource.Sync(). But my requirement is to update single row without triggering any other code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly then try `datasource.read()`

`datasource.sync()` is used to save any data item that has changed

`datasource.read()` reads all the data items from whatever remote service you have or from javascript array